# Create a rectangle over camera preview on android

Tags: android, camera

I want to take a picture through a selected rectangle area on top of camera preview which I choose.I mean, I will open camera and I will select an area on full screen. when I click button, only the selected area will be taken.

If I say where I will use it, I am making a game and I need to take players' photo which is just head of players. and I need to select an area. How can I create a rectangle and move it and will take photo in that selected area